# Sinch SDK android Sharing Videos, Audiosm Photos

Tags: sinch

Am using sinch sdk to create a chat application in my app. It is a group chat app without one to one messages. How do I intergrate sharing multimedia data like videos, audio or photos in my app using sinch?

Answer (score 0):

The sinch SDK is really good at 1on1 messaging, to do broadcast messages one to many is not really what the SDK is designed for. I would look at other solutions like Parse and Layer

Answer (score 0):

According to Sinch! the feature of sending media messages has not been released yet, therefore it only means that you are allowed to send text messages only.
Since, i am also working on a chat kinda thing using Sinch, you might wanna know that a group here can have a max. Of 10 people added to it, so keep that in mind while developing.☺