# Send Attachments Using Sinch SDK

Tags: android, parse-platform, sinch

I am currently working on a chat application using  [sinch sdk](https://github.com/sinch/android-messaging-tutorial). I have done with text chat till now and it is working fine . Now I want to send attachments (audio/video/images) . So how can I do it .
I have visited through  [parse tutorial](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#user-interface-loading-remote-images-in-rows) ,it has ability to store images ,But I didn't find a way to send attachments using sinch . I have visited some blogs like  [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380218/sinch-sdk-android-sharing-videos-audiosm-photos) but people are saying that sinch doesn't support audios/videos/images through chat .So Here I want to be sure about it .
Help me plz .
Thank You .

Comment: Have you got any help? I am stuck with same?

Comment: I am looking forward for help ... I am doing Research on it ,I'll revert you back when I'll get .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinch only support text, no attachments

Comment: Are you planning to integrate this functionality in sinch sdk ,If yes then how much time your team will take to complete this .